# Multiplying result from data query with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, multiplication

I'm having trouble multiplying the result from a database search from php in a jQuery script.
I echoed the db result it's a double type in the database. So just a number, and I want it to be multiplied with a number and a variable that takes a number.

I tried doing this by adding the number and the variable in the jQuery output
like so:

```
$.post('nutritional_value.php', {value:value}, function(data){
        $('#search_result2').html(data*uneseno*10);
        });
```

uneseno and 10, being the variable and number which I want it to multiply it with.
Instead I just get the direct value from the database.

This is the .php file:

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';
$value = $_POST['value'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT FAT FROM ccm WHERE NAME LIKE '$value%'");
while( $run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $fat = $run['FAT'];

            echo $fat;
}

    ?>
```

This is the script:

```
<script>
function funkcija() {
    var value = $('a').text();
    $('#hidden1').show();
    $('#jedinice_butt').click(function () {
        var odabrano = $("#dropdown option:selected").text();
        var uneseno = $("#input_jedinica").val();
        if (odabrano === "g") {
            $.post('nutritional_value.php', {
                value: value
            }, function (data) {

                $('#search_result2').html(data * uneseno * 10);
            });
        }
    });
}   
</script>
```

The uneseno variable is a number when I enter it in the input field.
Console doesn't show any errors or anything.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: you can try (parseInt(uneseon)*parseInt(data)*10).

Comment: @mehdinejati I get 0 as the output, no mather what number I enter in uneseno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
var uneseno = $("#input_jedinica").val();
```

val() return a string...

Solution: use parseFloat()

```
$.post('nutritional_value.php', {
            value: value
        }, function (data) {

            $('#search_result2').html(data * parseFloat(uneseno) * 10);
        });
```

Comment: maybe data is returning 0..., use an alert(data + "," + uneseno) to check wich is 0

Comment: nope, it alerts the value from DB and the one I entered. (0.3846,111)

Comment: fixed it!
$('#search_result2').html(data * parseInt(uneseno,10));

Thank you :)

Comment: I updated my answer, if $("#input_jedinica") can receive decimal numbers, you have to use parseFloat() (parseInt will truncate to integer)